# How to understand Coq type constructor var (t: T)

Tags: functional-programming, logic, coq

I am reading about mechanization of linear logic in Coq http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~iliano/projects/metaCLF2/inc/dl/papers/lsfa17.pdf and https://github.com/brunofx86/LL and I have trouble to understand the type constructors of the inductive type `term` from https://github.com/brunofx86/LL/blob/master/FOLL/LL/SyntaxLL.v:

```
Inductive term  :=
    |var (t: T) (* variables *)
    |cte (e:A) (* constants from the domain DT.A *)
    |fc1 (n:nat) (t: term) (* family of functions of 1 argument *)
    |fc2 (n:nat) (t1 t2: term). (* family of functions of 2 argument *)
```

I have two question regarding this sample (I am reading https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html along this paper):

- what is the (super)type of `term`? Software Foundations always specifies the (super)type of the new type, like `Inductive color : Type`;
- **the main question - how to understand type constructor `var (t: T)`?**. Software Foundation in its first chapter provides only two types of type constructors: constant `white : color` and function `primary : rgb → color`. But `var (t: T)` is very strange notation - it is not valid function type definition as it have no explicit return type and also it has no arrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your main question, the syntax `var (t : T)` when defining a constructor is just some alternative (shorter) syntax for `var : forall t : T, term`, which can just as well be written `var : T -> term` (since there is no occurrence of variable `t` in `term`).

Actually, you can check this by processing the definition, then the following command:

```
Print term.

(* and Coq displays the inductive type with the default syntax, that is:

  Inductive term : Type :=
    var : T -> term
  | cte : A -> term
  | fc1 : nat -> term -> term
  | fc2 : nat -> term -> term -> term
*)
```

Next (as shown by the Coq output above), the type of the datatype `term` is indeed `Type`.

I recall that in Coq, all types have also a type, and this latter will always be `Prop`, `Set` or `Type`. A "type of type" is usually called a sort. (The sort `Prop` deals with logical propositions while the sorts `Set` and `Type` deal with so-called "informative" types.)

Finally, it can be noted that `Type` does not refer to a fixed type, but to a given `Type_i` where the index `i >=0` is automatically determined and checked by Coq's kernel. For more information on this topic, see for example the first section of the [Universes chapter of CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html)