# What Coq function definition `Definition Term := forall T: Type, term T.` means?

Tags: functional-programming, logic, coq

I am reading about mechanization of linear logic in Coq http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~iliano/projects/metaCLF2/inc/dl/papers/lsfa17.pdf and https://github.com/brunofx86/LL and I have trouble to understand the the function definition `Term` (and other function definitions involving `forall`) from https://github.com/brunofx86/LL/blob/master/FOLL/LL/SyntaxLL.v:

```
Definition Term := forall T:Type,  term T. (* type for terms *)
Definition AProp := forall T:Type, aprop T. (* type for atomic propositions *)
```

Why we need `forall` construction in function definition, what additional meaning it gives? Is is creating some kind of set - i.e. - that function returns set of results - one result for each type?

I am reading http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/cpdt.pdf ''Chapter 12 Universes and Axioms'', this question is continuation to my previous question [How to understand Coq type constructor var (t: T)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718746/how-to-understand-coq-type-constructor-var-t-t) trying to understand this mentioned article.

Answer (score 3):

In Parametric HOAS, the parameter `T` represents the set of variables that can occur in a term. For example, if you want a term that uses at most two variables, it may have type `term bool` because `bool` has two inhabitants. A closed term (with no free variable) can thus naively be typed `term void`, where `void` is an empty type:

```
Inductive void := .
```

`term void` turns out to be equivalent to `forall A, term A` (you can apply the function `forall A, void -> A` in one direction, and just specialize in the other direction). This latter representation of closed terms is more convenient to embed in other open terms.